# Getting NSIS File Version with C#

Tags: c#, nsis, fileversioninfo

I have scripted an installer using NSIS and added version information via `VIProductVersion` and `VIAddVersionKey` commands.  When I view the properties of the compiled file, the version information is there as I expect it to be.

My problem is when I attempt to get the version information via the C# command `FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(fileName).FileVersion`, it returns an empty string.

Here is a quick way to replicate:

**NSIS Script**

```
!include LogicLib.nsh
!include FileFunc.nsh

!define PRODUCT_NAME "Installer"
!define PRODUCT_VERSION "1.0.0.2"

Name "${PRODUCT_NAME} ${PRODUCT_VERSION}"

VIProductVersion "${PRODUCT_VERSION}"
VIAddVersionKey ProductVersion "${PRODUCT_VERSION}"

OutFile "Setup.exe"

Section "Installer"
SectionEnd
```

**C# Code**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        FileVersionInfo fvi = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo("Setup.exe");

        if (fvi != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("File Version: {0}", fvi.FileVersion));
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Could not load file version info");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

This gives the output of:

```
File Version: 
Press any key to continue...
```

What do I need to get to read the `FileVersion` as `1.0.0.2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what I was doing wrong.  Even though it looked correct in the properties dialog, I was using the wrong value with `VIAddVersionKey`.  To have it read correctly, you should use `VIAddVersionKey FileVersion "${PRODUCT_VERSION}"`